# Differential reading problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Year 2003 was 10% of the global population internet users. 10 years later, 2013, the number had increased to 40%. A simple model to describe this growt is that the share of users increases with a velocity that is, in every moment, proportional to the product between the share of users and the share of non-users. After how long time (counting from 2003) will the share of internetusers be 90%?

My approach is to use a constant $k$ and a function $a$ which derivate $a'$ is the velocity. That gives me $$a' = ka-ka^2$$. But is that correct and how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known equation. See e.g.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Comment: Thanks, interesting, but I still can't solve it.

Comment: Read the article.

Comment: I've. I found an answer under "Logistic differential equation". But an answer doesn't mean that I understand it nor can solve it.